# How to make a loopback device appear and behave as a (removable) block device?

Tags: mount, block-device, removable-storage, loopback

If I create a loopback device, I can mount it manually, but it doesn't show up in Plasma  "Disks & Devices" as a newly attached Storage Volume (Removable Media), nor does it appear as an entry in Dolphin (under Devices) like any other usb disk or nvme harddisk would appear. I would like the loopback device upon creation to appear there as unmounted, such that a user can then click on it and mount it on-demand. Is this possible?

It doesn't specifically have to be recognized as removable, but I would like for it to appear like other devices that have been attached (since boot or hot-plugged), and be un-/mountable & listed in Dolphin/Plasma like any other.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: you can patch either the kernel or KDE to make them work like you want but that's too much.